# Stop googlebot spidering Google Street view

Tags: api, web-crawler, googlebot

Many of the pages on my website have Google Street View (static version) on them. As a result, Googlebot runs and generates a lot of activity on my Google API account costing quite a lot of billing.

I don't want to stop Google spidering my site or discovering my own images but I want somehow to detect that a bot is accessing the site and somehow comment out Streetview for bots only.

This:
    `User-agent: Googlebot-Image`
    `Disallow: /images/image.jpg`
won't work in this case as Google still spiders but just doesn't include the result.

Answer (score 0):

Just a random thought but perhaps in answer to my own question:

1. Put the Street View a new web page that displays in an iframe.
2. Put a NOINDEX in the META tags on the new page.